# Registered Users and unregistered users

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a users table for registered users. These registered users can add contacts that have registered (Registered users) and also contacts that have not registered (That can register in future).

What is the best database structure?

1. Should I create two User tables (Registered and unregistered) having
   ID as primary key and using the Email as a unique identifier.
2. Should I store all contacts (registered and unregistered in the same
   table #Users Table) having in mind that not-existing users/emails
   can be added to the table making it to have alot of users that may
   never exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage a website since 6 years and I have all the users in the same table with a column named "profile", with any problem at all. Is very useful to have all in the same table.
You could have a boolean column: registered and non registered.

Comment: Thanks @Zeek. What if a user tries to enter a contact and makes a mistake with the email address (say userA@foo.com and types userB@foo.com) that automatically creates two users with the same name, wont it make the table to have alot of data that may never be used

Comment: You must check the email with twice input.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create two tables you can create separate column for user_status it can be registered or not and email can be a unique column and for non registered users it will be null (violating normalization principals )  but it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

To stay nth normalized and flexible in your design to use Contact information for purposes beyond even your description I would go with.

Contacts Table -- everyone with shared contact details
Users Table - specific to users and details in regards to user accounts (e.g. encrypted/hash password and email)

Now if you only want a 1 to 1 relationship between User & Contact simply include a foreign key to Contacts Table on the Users Table.

If you want to allow for a one to many, or many to many use a 3rd table to store relationships between users and contacts.  I would see this as rare and it is definitely very difficult to manage, but I have learned from my own guest data environment that email addresses are never really unique to an individual.  Families share!  Husband wife, kids, etc.  Also depending on what you are selling/doing the same person may want 2 accounts 1 for business and 1 for personal, Or 1 she doesn't care about her husband seeing and 1 she does.  Plus if you ever want to allow for groups to use the same account you might want to capture all of the contact information.